# regex get words between braces and quotes (just the words)

Tags: ruby, regex

I got a string in Ruby like this:

```
str = "enum('cpu','hdd','storage','nic','display','optical','floppy','other')"
```

Now i like to return just a array with only the words (not quotes, thats between the round braces (...).  The regex below works, buts includes 'enum' which i don't need.

```
str.scan(/\w+/)
```

expected result should be:

```
{"OPTICAL"=>"optical", "DISPLAY"=>"display", "OTHER"=>"other", "FLOPPY"=>"floppy", "STORAGE"=>"storage", "NIC"=>"nic", "HDD"=>"hdd", "CPU"=>"cpu"}
```

thanks!

Comment: you're sure you won't have any contractions or possessives?

Comment: yeah, its actually the sql_type from Rails (active model). Im sure that will contain just simple strings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd suggest using [negative lookahead](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) to eliminate words followed by `(`:

```
str.scan(/\w+(?!\w|\()/)
```

*Edit:* regex updated, now it also excludes `\w`, so it won't match word prefixes.

Comment: thx! but this returns: ["enu", "cpu", "hdd", "storage", "nic", "display", "optical", "floppy", "other"]

Comment: @Rogier lol you're right! answer updated, now it should work fine (tested on rubular, got the expected result).

Answer (score 1):

Based on the output you wanted this will work.

```
str = "enum('cpu','hdd','storage','nic','display','optical','floppy','other')"
arr = str.scan(/'(\w+)'/)
hs = Hash[arr.map { |e| [e.first.upcase,e.first] }]
p hs #=> {"CPU"=>"cpu", "HDD"=>"hdd", "STORAGE"=>"storage", "NIC"=>"nic", "DISPLAY"=>"display", "OPTICAL"=>"optical", "FLOPPY"=>"floppy", "OTHER"=>"other"}
```